# Parameter valueAccesor select2 knockout.js comes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select2 on my page. Both configured as multiple. When doing the custom binding using ko.bindingHandlers.select2 .... the valueAccessor parameter corresponding to a select2 comes undefined. When I remove one of them, it works normally. When I put both select2 there it only works for one.

Meu html

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="Ids_Usuarios" data-bind="select2: $.DesafioNet.select2.Usuarios, selectedOptions: $root.Ids_Usuarios" data-filtro="@jsonString"></select>


<select class="form-control edits" multiple="multiple" id="Ids_Grupos" data-bind="select2: $.DesafioNet.select2.Grupos, selectedOptions: $root.Ids_Grupos" data-filtro="@jsonString"></select>
```

Meu javascript

```
ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {

       

        var wrapperFunction = function () {
           

            var resultValueAccessor = valueAccessor();
            var select2 = typeof resultValueAccessor == "function" ? resultValueAccessor() : ko.utils.unwrapObservable(resultValueAccessor);

            // Verifica se o select2 está usando carregamento Ajax
            if (select2 != undefined && select2.ajax !== undefined && select2.ajax) {

                var array = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindings().selectedOptions()) || [];
                if (array.length > 0) {

                    select2.IsWaitingAjax = true;

                    var Obj =
                    {
                        Ids: array
                    };

                    DesafioNet.Ajax(options.ajax.url, Obj, function (data) {

                        if (data.length > 0) {

                            var data = $.map(data, function (item) {
                                item.id = item.Id;
                                item.text = select2.getItemText(item);
                                return item;
                            });

                            $(element).empty();

                            data.forEach(function (item) {
                                $(element).append(new Option(item.text, item.id, true, true));
                            });

                            $(element).data('custom-select2-data-ajax-first-time', data);

                        }
                        select2.IsWaitingAjax = false;

                        $(element).select2(select2);


                    }, null, true);


                }

            } else {
                // Carrega os valores normalmente sem o carregamento Ajax
                //$(element).select2();

                var obj = valueAccessor(),
                    allBindingsnew = allBindings(),
                    lookupKey = allBindingsnew.lookupKey;
                var resultValueAccessor = valueAccessor();


                if (lookupKey) {
                    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsnew.value);
                    $(element).select2('data', ko.utils.arrayFirst(obj.data.results, function (item) {
                        return item[lookupKey] === value;
                    }));
                }


            }
            $(element).select2(select2);
            $(element).trigger("change.select2");

        };

        setTimeout(wrapperFunction, 100); // Chama a função wrapper após 100 ms
        

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        
        
        var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        ko.unwrap(allBindings.get('selectedOptions'));

        $(element).select2(options);
        $(element).trigger('change');
      
    }
};
```

I don't know why when I put the two selects2 on the screen the valueAccessor only works for one.